# Better way to return debug information instead of using lots of if-else

Tags: c#, if-statement

So I have a boolean method that is used to verify if a command is valid. This is used inside of an engine in which it verifies that the process can continue or not. This is the validation method:

```
private bool CommandIsValid(WC command)
        {
            if (command.Address == null ||
                command.UserId < 0 ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.CurrencyCode) ||
                command.Amount < .01m ||
                command.Address.PrimitiveAddress == null ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.Address.Source) ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.Address.PrimitiveAddress.City) ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.Address.PrimitiveAddress.Country) ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.Address.PrimitiveAddress.FirstName) ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.Address.PrimitiveAddress.LastName) ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.Address.PrimitiveAddress.Region) ||
                command.Address.Created <= DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

And is called here inside of my method here:

```
if (!CommandIsValid(cmd))
{
    _logger.Debug("Invalid command);
}
```

The issue is that I want to have some type of information regarding what failed validation. The best solution would have a list of what validations didn't pass, so I could relay that in my logging debugger. Obviously I could do this using a bunch of if-else statements, but it seems sloppy, as having a bunch of if else statements seems very poor style and I was wondering if there is any way in c# or in general I can do to avoid this.

Comment: Is that a typo? `_logger.Debug("Invalid command);`

Comment: Instead of returning a `bool`, return a container of `bool` values when first is the overall status False/True then each one reflects a condition of the above. If first element is False, then you check which condition (index) is the false. Looks like it is fixed in size then you may just agree on the sequence.

Comment: Another option is to move the validation logic inside the type, implementing some interface like [IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: No that is not a typo, _logger is just a logger. I'm not familiar with containers, do you mind adding a solution so i can attempt this? Thanks!

Comment: don't see anything wrong with your existing method

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are many different ways to approach this. You should start by trying _something_, and if it doesn't work for you for some reason, then explain why. It's not even clear here whether you would be satisfied simply knowing the first condition that failed, or if you want a way to report all of the conditions that failed.

Comment: It is not the best or fanciest approach. But I added the answer

Comment: After thinking about it, I sort of agree with @PeterDuniho so I retracted my answer as it ended up just being a rehash of what you are doing with my personal preference added in. I would try to reword your question.

Comment: I updated the description. Overall it's a very simple question, how do I avoid using a bunch of if else statements to allow the logger to use.

Comment: Your edit hasn't narrowed the question any. "Without `if`-`else`" leaves open a lot of other possibilities. Frankly, the best approach is for the data structure to not be able to be invalid in the first place. I.e. all these values you're checking, it shouldn't be possible to construct an instance of the data structure with invalid values. Barring that, you can use any number of data validation techniques, some supported by .NET, some implemented yourself according to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with DataAnnotations and it's associated [Validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) class?

It would require modifications to your object.

```
public PrimitiveAddress
{
[Required]
public string City {get;set;}
}
```

and then you use it like so:

```
var context = new ValidationContext(command.Address.PrimitiveAddress);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(recipe, context, results);

if (!isValid)
{
    foreach (var validationResult in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

if you've got a base command class you could probably add it in a more generic fashion.  You can create your own validation attributes, use [IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) for anything complex, customize the error messages

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="This is required.")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a `bool`, return a container of `bool` values where first is the overall status False/True then each one reflects a condition of the above. If first element is False, then you check which condition (index) is the false. Looks like it is fixed in size then you may just agree on the sequence.

Something like this:

```
List<bool> YourFunction(YourDebuggerThing Input)
{
    List<bool> Result = new List<bool>();

    if (Input.Condition1 == false || Input.Condition2 == false || Input.Condition3 == false || Input.Condition4 == false || Input.Condition5 == false)
        Result.Add(false); // first element is always the overall status

    if(Input.Condition1 == false) Result.Add(false); else Result.Add(true); // element 2 is condition 1
    if(Input.Condition2 == false) Result.Add(false); else Result.Add(true); // element 3 is condition 2
    // ..
    // ConditionN

    return Result;
}
```

Comment: So this is sort of what I was thinking of, but it involves a bunch of if else statements. Is there any cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Of course there are. Plenty of ways. But this was from the top of my head. To find better ways we need to research

Comment: Ok, because this is sort of the whole if-else thing I wanted to avoid in the first place

Comment: Validation rules are prone to change frequently due to new business requirements. With your code the developers not only have to maintain the validation function `YourFunction` but also its callers that rely on the ordering of bools inside the returned list. On a bigger scale this will turn into a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride As I mentioned in a reply comment to the OP's request of showing him how to do it. [**Definitely not the best nor the fanciest approach**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355194/better-way-to-return-debug-information-instead-of-using-lots-of-if-else/39355325?noredirect=1#comment66040621_39355194).

Answer (score 0):

One idea might be to implement your checks within the Get/Set methods of the class' properties, using a custom exception. Such as;

```
public class PrimitiveAddresses
{
    private string _city;
    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            if(_city != null) {return _city;}
            else {throw new CommandInvalidException("No valid city provided");}                 
        }
        set
        {
            _city = value;
        }

    }

}

public class CommandInvalidException: Exception
{
    public CommandInvalidException(string message)
    : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

Then during you implementation, use a try/catch to handle the specific error;

```
public void foo()
{
    try
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.Address.PrimitiveAddress.City)){} // Ect
    }
    catch (CommandInvalidException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Command invalid due to " + e.message);
        // Or any other way you want to deal with the missing data
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)